# req.body empty in express 4x using app.use(express.json()) in vscode REST client

Tags: node.js, json, express, post, body-parser

I was working on my express backend and was able to `console.log` and send back body data on post request on `res.send(req.body)` but after few moments with some changes the code doesn't seemed to work at all and retuned empty string on sending post request like this:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())
app.post('/profile', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});
app.listen(5000);
```

**Result**

> Request made with VScode Rest client Extension

[image]

And even instead of using `app.use(express.json())` I also tried `body-parser` which also returns the same result.

So, what should I do and is this problem with only `express 4x`

Comment: The code looks good, try calling your server with Postman?

Comment: oh thanks @JeremyThille for making me aware of it. I think my rest client isnt working properly. but when i tried with postman, it seems to work very well.

Comment: Postman is an excellent tool to query API endpoints.

Comment: @JeremyThille indeed I'll be using that. thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had the same issue,
It's a minor thing but hard to figure out.

It's all about the spaces, you shouldn't have spaces in the wrong places.

Not working :
[image]

Working :

[image]